# How can I improve my code so I don't get timing errors?

Tags: signals, verilog, fpga, timing, dac

I am writing code to interface with [this](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodda3/reference-manual) DAC to make a sine wave. I have a sine LUT that generates values just fine, along with a DAC controller. The controller brings CS to low, feeds in the 16-bit integer bit by bit, and pulses CS to high after 16 counts. As it does pulses, it also sends an enable pulse to the sin LUT to count up one more number. This code seems to not work very well, as I'm getting spikes in output. This is because the clock reads CS as low when it is supposed to be high (figure 1), causing the DAC to read in 17 bits (in other words, read the current number's MSB as the previous number's LSB), which causes the awkward spikes (figure 2).

How could I better organize this code so that I minimize the risk of running into this timing issue?

```
module DAC_Control(
  input [15:0]data_in,
  input counter_enable,
  input clk,
  input rst,
  output data_out,
  output reg cs,
  output reg enable
  );

//bit counter
  reg [3:0] bit_counter;

//to help with shifting
  reg [15:0] shifter;

//shifter
  always @(posedge (clk)) begin
    if (rst) begin
      bit_counter <= 4'b0;
      shifter <= 0;
      end
    else if (counter_enable == 1) begin
        shifter <= data_in;
        bit_counter <= 4'b0;
    end
    else begin
      shifter <= shifter << 1; // shifting
      bit_counter <= bit_counter + 1'b1; // counter
    end
  end

  reg cs_hold;

  always @(posedge (clk)) begin
    if (rst) begin
      enable <= 1'b0;
      cs <= 1'b1;
      end
    else if (bit_counter == 4'b1110) begin
      enable <= 1'b1;
      cs <= 1'b0;
    end
    else if (bit_counter == 4'b1111) begin
      enable <= 1'b0;
      cs <= 1'b1;
    end
    else if (cs_hold == 1) begin
      enable <= 1'b0;
      cs <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
      enable <= 1'b0; // generate enable signals
      cs <= 1'b0;
    end
  end


  assign data_out = shifter[15];

endmodule
```

**Figure 1. Yellow is DIN, Blue is CS, green is clock**

[image: figure 1]

**Figure 2. The output of the DAC**

[image: figure 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which vendor your FPGA is from, however, most have timing constraints which allow you to define the relationship between your clock and the data.  They use the idea of virtual clocks.  Think of it like there is an external clock and you get to say what the differential is between the clocks.  If the clock is directly generated from the FPGA, and not from some external source I think you can set some of the CLKs values to 0.

By setting these kind of constraints, you make it so the data output is moved relative to the clk and it will be "consistent and controlled".

```
+----------+                +--------+
| FPGA     |----Data_out--->|  DAC   |
+----------+                +--------+
     CLKs /\               CLKd /\
          |                      |
          +-------sys_clk--------+
```

Here is solution for Altera devices using SDC to time an output.

```
#specify the maximum external clock delay to the FPGA
set CLKs_max 0.200
#specify the minimum external clock delay to the FPGA
set CLKs_min 0.100
#specify the maximum external clock delay to the external device
set CLKd_max 0.200
#specify the minimum external clock delay to the external device
set CLKd_min 0.100
#specify the maximum setup time of the external device
set tSU 0.125
#specify the minimum setup time of the external device
set tH 0.100
#specify the maximum board delay
set BD_max 0.180
#specify the minimum board delay
set BD_min 0.120
#create a clock 10ns
create_clock -period 10 -name sys_clk [get_ports sys_clk]
#create the associated virtual input clock
create_clock -period 10 -name virt_sys_clk
#create the output maximum delay for the data output from the FPGA that
#accounts for all delays specified
set_output_delay -clock virt_sys_clk \
    -max [expr $CLKs_max + $BD_max + $tSU - $CLKd_min] \
    [get_ports {data_out[*]}]
#create the output minimum delay for the data output from the FPGA that
#accounts for all delays specified
set_output_delay -clock virt_sys_clk \
    -min [expr $CLKs_min + $BD_min - $tH - $CLKd_max] \
    [get_ports {data_out[*]}]
```

Alternately, if you can NOT control the relationship between data and clock with constraints, which seems cheesy to even suggest (And if true, please tell me the vendor so I can stay from them) you could make the situation better by following the suggestion of the previous answer, by changing your posedge to negedge.  Just bear in mind, this could be flexible from build to build as the output may not be constrained the way you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is something that I have been trying to understand for awhile. I have four remaining questions based on this: 1- I get these maximum and minimum values from the DAC timing constraints, right? 2- can you elaborate on what you mean when you say "the data output is moved relative to the data" 3- My board is from Xilinx, I've looked through the timing constraints user guide and didn't see the code to execute these constraints, any idea where I can find them/ what to google? 4- do you have suggestions on further reading about clocks that's geared towards a beginner?

Comment: 1. Yes, you get them direct from the data sheet.  You can make them tighter if you like, but not too tight as you add more delay routing and eat up resources in the chip to make it work.

Comment: 2.  I mis-typed that.  I meant to say data relative to clock.  I just corrected that in the answer.  3.  If you are using Vivando, here is a link... see chapter 4.  It's not the same as Altera, but I think you will get it.  You say, I want my data to change this many ns after or before the clock. [vivando using constraints](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_1/ug903-vivado-using-constraints.pdf)   4 - Google Xilinx timing constraints and you should get some university presentations and lessons in there.

Answer (score 2):

DAC is using rising edge to sample the data:

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5541A.pdf

```
Serial Data Input. This device accepts 16-bit words. Data is clocked into the serial input register on the rising edge of SCLK.
```

You might want to try to generate data_out and cs on the falling edge of the clk.